# Is there any way to trigger third party API in middle journey , to send mass email from third party app ,if we are not using Sales cloud data

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect, marketingcloudapi, mass-email

Is there any way to trigger third party API in middle journey , to send mass email from third party app.

Comment: If my answer helped, please mark it as accepted (via the checkmark icon next to it) so others can easily see this has been resolved. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This would be a use case for creating a custom activity which requires development up front, but can then be conveniently used inside a journey for your marketers. In the interface it is then displayed just like any other activity and can be added to your journey canvas via drag and drop. Configuration steps can be fully configured to your needs.

However, you should definitely give your use case a second thought on why to hand over from a tool capable of mass mailing to another one. Especially as a journey is a 1:1 customer journey per contact and not a mass mailing process in the first place. So is there a need to invoce a mass email for every contact going through a journey? Because that's what would happen with a custom activity.

To get a picture of how this could work, have a look at the following resources:

- [SF Documentation - Build Custom Activities and Events](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/creating-activities.htm)
- [Code example by Salesforce](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/sfmc-example-jb-custom-activity)
- [Code example of one custom activity I created (however, it is a custom split activity, but you can get a picture of the components by looking at it)](https://github.com/mslabina/sfmc-servicecloud-customsplit)
  --> Background on why I created this activity: [How to fix wrong Decision Split evaluation in SFMC](https://markus.codes/2017/07/06/how-to-fix-wrong-decision-split-evaluation-in-sfmc)
- [Errorhandling and Performance Settings for Journey Builder Custom Activities](https://markus.codes/2020/04/24/salesforce-marketing-cloud-journey-builder-custom-activities-enhancement)